# Load split view controller from more than one file

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a big problem with a split view controller. The code works great but there is a lot of information in one file that I want to split into two or more files. I want to accomplish this so the information loads from different files.

For example:category.swift,name.swift 
the file inside load in viewcontroller.swift

```
// Setup the Search Controller
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
definesPresentationContext = true
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

// Setup the Scope Bar
searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", "Chocolate", "Hard", "Other"]
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

candies = [
Candy(category:"Chocolate", name:"Chocolate Bar"),
Candy(category:"Chocolate", name:"Chocolate Chip"),
```

..........about 3000 examples like this

```
Candy(category:"Qukullad", name:"keks")]

if let splitViewController = splitViewController {
let controllers = splitViewController.viewControllers
detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController
 }
}
```

Comment: Why did you decide to hardcode the candies in the source code. All 3000 of them? Rather than, for example, have them as some external file (which can be any format you want, Json for example, or an info.plist) and then have your code read that external file?

Comment: i would like to do that (add extern file )but i don't know how can i do it that's my question can you help me about this pleas